# wrong texttrimming in gridview

Tags: gridview, trim

I have a gridview with cells and header set to a textblock with `texttrimming=CharacterEllipsis`.
Sometimes it happens that the text is trimmed even if there is enough place to draw the whole text.
This is occurring both in header cell and data rows.

Here's an example from the header cell w/o trimming and same width:

[image: Header cell]

Any hints what kind of style applied to the gridview columns could cause a behaviour like this?